# alternative relationship deprecated warning

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Cypher query:

```
MATCH (x) WHERE x.uuid = "41f64ab1-6009-4e95-b22b-c833525f6edb" MATCH p = 
(o)-[:CONTAINS|:HAVING*]->(x) WHERE labels(o) IN ['Box', 'Package'] RETURN p
```

Running it in Neo4j browser results in a warning:

```
**WARNING: This feature is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.**

The semantics of using colon in the separation of alternative relationship 
types in conjunction with the use of variable binding, inlined property 
predicates, or variable length will change in a future version.
```

How can I re-write this query to eliminate this warning?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This deprecation is not about inability of using relationship type alternatives but about its syntax – see [cypher deprecations in version 3.2](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/deprecations-additions-removals-compatibility/#cypher-deprecations-additions-removals-3.2). Only first type has colon now, i.e. not `:R1|:R2` but `:R1|R2`. Deprecation warning in Neo4j browser suggests that former syntax will have new semantics in the future.

Specifying relationship type in a pattern is actually much more effective than filtering paths ex-post which is the way that the workaround by Tom Geudens is executed.

Answer (score 0):

This might do it :

```
MATCH (x) WHERE x.uuid = "41f64ab1-6009-4e95-b22b-c833525f6edb"
MATCH p = (o)-[*]->(x) 
WHERE labels(o) IN ['Box', 'Package']
AND ALL (rs IN relationships(p) WHERE type(rs) IN ['CONTAINS','HAVING'])
RETURN p
```

Hope this helps.