# Neo4j - Match by multiple relationship types

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to match between entities by multiple relationship types.

Is it possible to say the following query:

```
match (Yoav:Person{name:"Yoav"})-[:liked & watched & ... ]->(movie:Movie) return movie
```

I need "and" between all the relation types; Yova liked and watched and .. a movie.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like:

```
match (gal:Person{name:"Yoav"})-[:liked|:watched|:other]->(movie:Movie) 
return movie
```

Take a look in the docs: [Match on multiple relationship types](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/match/#match-on-multiple-rel-types)

**EDIT:**

From the comments:

> I need "and" between the relation types.. you gave me an "or"

In this case, you can do:

```
match (Yoav:Person{name:"Yoav"})-[:liked]->(movie:Movie),
(Yoav)-[:watched]->(movie),
(Yoav)-[:other]->(movie)
return movie
```

Comment: :liked|:watched|:other == liked and watched and other, :liked|watched|other == liked or watched or other ?

Comment: liked|watched|other == liked or watched or other

Comment: I need "and" between the relation types.. you gave me an "or"

Comment: I understand. In this case I believe has no way to do it using only one relationship in the pattern matching.

Comment: then How would you implement it?

Comment: You can use: `match (Yoav:Person{name:"Yoav"})-[:liked]->(movie:Movie),
(Yoav)-[:watched]->(movie),
(Yoav)-[:other]->(movie)
return movie
`

Comment: Please update your answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Neo4j Desktop gives a warning that this ability of using colons for multiple relationship types is slotted to be deprecated and a new method to be used soon. I'm not sure how the new syntax is going to look like.

Comment: @MichaelBlack according to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45790779/alternative-relationship-deprecated-warning)
> i.e. not :R1|:R2 but :R1|R2.

Comment: In the newer versions of neo4j, for the OR expression, you have to lose the colons: ```match (gal:Person{name:"Yoav"})-[:liked|watched|other]->(movie:Movie) 
return movie```