# Combine multiple relationship types and return data from both relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So, I'm currently writing a Cypher query where I want to get all entries in the database and their relationships to import them into Cytoscape for further analysis.

I want to combine two relationship types to one variable, use a WHERE operation on them and return the results. Let's say I want to get a list for interesting movies, based on either how much the person spent (e.g. Collector's edition) or if he actually managed to watch the movie.

Right now, my query looks like this, [based on this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46132345/neo4j-match-by-multiple-relationship-types):

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[rel:`watched`|`bought`]->(c:Movie)
WHERE
(rel.watch_min >= 50) or (rel.bought_price > 10)
RETURN p, rel, c
```

Now, in the Neo4j browser, this works. But the output of `rel` only has relationship properties from the `watched` relationship, and not the combined one.

How does the query need to look like so that `rel` contains both properties, from `watched` and `bought`?

What I basically want to write is this:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r1:`watched`|r2:`bought`]->(c:Movie)
WHERE
(rl.watch_min >= 50) or (r2.bought_price > 10)
RETURN p, r1, r2, c
```

But unfortunately, this is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If I create some sample data:

```
CREATE
  (p:Person{id: 123})-[:watched{watch_min: 60}]->(m:Movie{name:'Foo'}),
  (p)-[:bought{bought_price:99}]->(m);
```

and perform your first query, I get this result:

```
╒══════════╤═══════════════════╤══════════════╕
│"p"       │"rel"              │"c"           │
╞══════════╪═══════════════════╪══════════════╡
│{"id":123}│{"bought_price":99}│{"name":"Foo"}│
├──────────┼───────────────────┼──────────────┤
│{"id":123}│{"watch_min":60}   │{"name":"Foo"}│
└──────────┴───────────────────┴──────────────┘
```

So, your query is working just fine and is returning both relationship types.

If you actually want the properties of all the relationships between a pair of nodes to be combined, you can use the [APOC](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/) function `apoc.map.mergeList` to do the combining:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[rel:watched|bought]->(c:Movie)
WHERE (rel.watch_min >= 50) OR (rel.bought_price > 10)
RETURN p, c, apoc.map.mergeList(COLLECT(rel)) AS props;
```

which returns this result:

```
╒══════════╤══════════════╤══════════════════════════════════╕
│"p"       │"c"           │"props"                           │
╞══════════╪══════════════╪══════════════════════════════════╡
│{"id":123}│{"name":"Foo"}│{"bought_price":99,"watch_min":60}│
└──────────┴──────────────┴──────────────────────────────────┘
```

*However, if multiple relationships have the same property, then this approach gives you no control over which one you end up with.*

Comment: Oh yeah, I messed up the example, sorry. The WHERE had a condition dependent on both properties, e.g.  `WHERE (rel.watch_min >= 50) OR (rel.watch_min < 30 and rel.bought_price > 10)`, assuming there are multiple relationships going from or to two nodes where these properties exist.

With your example: 
`MATCH (p:Person)-[rel:\`watched\`|\`bought\`]->(c:Movie) WHERE (rel.watch_min >= 50) OR (rel.watch_min > 55 and rel.bought_price > 10) RETURN p, c, rel`
This is what I want to have as a query, but this only returns the watch_min and not the other property.

Comment: Point 1: Let's give `(rel.watch_min >= 50)` the name "A", and give `(rel.watch_min > 55 and rel.bought_price > 10)` the name "B". If B is true, then A is also true. So (A || B) is actually logically the same as just A by itself. Point 2: There is also a subtle problem with the Cypher code you used, but you should probably open a new question to keep things less confusing.

Comment: Damn, I messed up the values in the second code again, the value should be 30 like in the first code block. Of course watch_min should be less than 50, but yeah, you see my brain is pretty messed up at this point. Will properly reopen and carefully take my time to proof read...