# How to match multiple relationships to different nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

### What I am trying to get to

I am trying to get nodes of outgoing relationships in separate columns. The resulting data should look like the following:

| node1 | nodeRel1 | nodeRel2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| {...} | [{...}, {...}, ...] | [{...}, {...}, ...] |
| {...} | [{...}, {...}, ...] | [{...}, {...}, ...] |

Where `node1` is the starting node with label `Label1`, `nodeRel1` are all the nodes connected to `node1` through `REL1` with label `Label2`, and `nodeRel2` are all the nodes connected to `node1` through `REL2` with label `Label3`.
**EDIT:**
To specify, this is quite doable with two relationships like so (as pointed out by @nimrod serok): `MATCH ()-[]-(origin)-[]-()`, but this only works with two relationships. This needs to be extended to three, five, an arbitrary amount.

### What I have tried

The first thing I tried was:

```
MATCH (node1:Label1)-[:REL1|:REL2]->(node2)
RETURN node1, collect(node2)
```

Collecting `node2` would combine the results of different labels in one list under one column, so that would not work.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46132546/10806063) explains why using multiple matches won't work. (TLDR: it turns into an `AND` condition, as opposed to the `OR` type I am looking for.

Writing two separate queries and using `UNION` to combine them would not work, as unions need the `RETURN` structures to be the same, as per the [docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/union/). In my case, the first query would look like `RETURN node1, collect(nodeRel1)`, and the second like `RETURN node1, collect(nodeRel2)`, which are of different types.

### What now?

I figured I would be able to achieve this by using `RETURN` as follows:

```
RETURN node1, collect(nodeRel1), collect(nodeRel2)
```

Now, however, I am quite lost when it comes to writing the `MATCH` clause. What query would give me the desired data? And, equally important, why?

Thanks in advance,
Nils

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options here, one of them is:
`MATCH` the origin node and then `OPTIONAL MATCH` which relationship type you need (since it is not mandatory that it will exist). The last part is to `collect` each type's nodes

```
MATCH (n:Person)
WITH n
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[:LIKES]-(m)
WITH n, m
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[:LOVES]-(t)
RETURN n, collect(distinct(m)) as likes, collect(distinct(t)) as loves
```

For this sample data:

```
MERGE (b:Person {name: "Bob" })
MERGE (c:Person {name: "Charles" })
MERGE (a:Person {name: "Anna" })
MERGE (d:Person {name: "Kira" })
MERGE (e:Person {name: "Dan" })
MERGE (f:Person {name: "El" })

MERGE (a)-[:LIKES]-(b)
MERGE (a)-[:LIKES]-(c) 
MERGE (a)-[:LIKES]-(d) 
MERGE (e)-[:LOVES]-(a)
MERGE (e)-[:LOVES]-(b) 
MERGE (f)-[:LOVES]-(a) 
MERGE (d)-[:LOVES]-(b) 
MERGE (f)-[:LOVES]-(a)
```

It gave me this:

```
╒══════════════════╤════════════════════════════╤════════════════════════════╕
│"n"               │"likes"                     │"loves"                     │
╞══════════════════╪════════════════════════════╪════════════════════════════╡
│{"name":"Dan"}    │[]                          │[{"name":"Bob"},{"name":"Ann│
│                  │                            │a"}]                        │
├──────────────────┼────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"El"}     │[]                          │[{"name":"Anna"}]           │
├──────────────────┼────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"Bob"}    │[{"name":"Anna"}]           │[{"name":"Dan"},{"name":"Kir│
│                  │                            │a"}]                        │
├──────────────────┼────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"Charles"}│[{"name":"Anna"}]           │[]                          │
├──────────────────┼────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"Anna"}   │[{"name":"Charles"},{"name":│[{"name":"El"},{"name":"Dan"│
│                  │"Kira"},{"name":"Bob"}]     │}]                          │
├──────────────────┼────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"Kira"}   │[{"name":"Anna"}]           │[{"name":"Bob"}]            │
└──────────────────┴────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: `MATCH (t)-[:REL1]-(n:Person)-[:REL2]-(m)` works for two relationships. I have updated the question, thank you.

Comment: Updated the answer to support several types

Comment: Why are the first and second match the same, aside from the `OPTIONAL` match and the label being specified on `n`? This also does not seem to work on my own data set (I only get the results of the first relationship), which seems to only differ in the labels not being the same on each target node. Do you have any ideas on what might be going wrong?  @nimrod serok

Comment: Updated the first match. My bad

Comment: Ah, so this way you make the origin node mandatory to retrieve, after which you optionally match any relationships. Smart! Thank you very much sir. Have a great day!